# unable to update WCF service in the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

im using a WCF serivce for my project. Recently i updated the service and published it to the server. Now when i try to update the service in my project it gives an error.

ERROR:

There was an error downloading 'http://sample.sample.com/sample/sample.asmx'.

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://sample.sample.com/sample/sample.asmx'.

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://sample.sample.com/sample/sample.asmx. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: What happens when you roll your deployment back?

Comment: a `WCF` service shouldn't be a `asmx` and `svc` instead.

Comment: wcf service should be svc not asmx. thats a normal web service

Comment: @PetarVučetin same thing happen. actually this web service created by someone else. i had to modify it. i had the service code and i uploaded it to the server. when im trying to update it from my project then i get this error. so i had to run the service in locally and configure the service reference to localhost:// . but i dont understand the reason for this. live service is working when browsing.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh thank you.